# Get external api request body in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have an api call and in this calling another api. My requirement to store all api calls request body i.e., for any issues we can check application insights data with api URL information and parameters.

Using the code shown here, I was able to get first api request body but unable to read external api request body.

Please let me know the best way to achieve the task

Thanks in advance

```
private async Task LogRequest(HttpContext context, string correlationID)              
{
    context.Request.EnableBuffering();

    aiLogger.LogPageView(context.Request.Path.Value);

    using (var requestStream = _recyclableMemoryStreamManager.GetStream())
    {
        await context.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(requestStream);
        string requestBody = ReadStreamInChunks(requestStream); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would do this:

```
using var reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body);
json = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
```